# RDP上でデュアルモニターを使用したい

Tags: centos, rdp

現在`FreeRDP`をインストールして試してみようと思い立ち、
`yum install freerdp*`で`freerdp v1.0.2`の一式をインストールしました。
`xfreerdp -u hoge hogehost:3389`にて、RDP接続が出来たことも確認しました。
`xprop -root`にて使用しているモニタを出して、`xfreerdp -X monitorID`を実行できることも確認しました。

現在利用しているバージョンが`yum`のリポジトリ上の最新ではありますが、
調べたところ`v2.0.0`らしきバージョンがあり、その上では`/multimon`があるみたいなのですが、
`v1.0.2`でデュアルモニターを利用してRDPできる方法はありますか？

以下の理由によってバージョンアップしていないだけなので、
「`パッケージされた新しいバージョンのrpm`があってこうすればいける」や、
「他のツールでこうすれば簡単」でも助かります。

- バージョンアップしようとすると`yum`だけで完結しないこと
- 依存関係をそろえるために、必要なモジュールを探しきれないこと
- [ここ](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/PreBuilds)とか、[ここ](https://pkgs.org/download/freerdp)で`CentOS`向けが確認できなくてパッケージ化されていない
- 最終的にセットアップ手順を確立しておきたいので煩雑にはしたくない

クライアント：`CentOS 7`
ホスト：`Windows 7`

Comment: `freerdp-2.0.0-rc4`はベータ版で、配布されているアーカイブには`*.spec`ファイルも含まれているので自分でrpmパッケージを作成することも可能ですが、依存関係のパッケージを入れるのが手間かもしれません (必要なパッケージ名自体は表示されます)。 / もしくは代わりにVNCをそれぞれに入れた方が簡単に済むかも。

Comment: @cubick はい、試しに別ディストリビューション向けのものを入れてみようとしたときに必要なリストは表示されていました。最終手段としてはパッケージをビルドすることも視野に入れてみようとは思っています。（やはりコメント頂いた通り手間なので、他の方法があればいいなぁとは思ってます）

Comment: 試してないのでご参考まで。 ビルド手順です。 https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Compilation 文中では "rhel based" と書かれてる部分を実施してみるとうまく行きそうな気がします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

調べては見たのですが、

- `v1.0.2`では`multimon`と等価の命令は無さそう。
- `v2.0.0`がβ版のため、試したい人はビルドしてね。という感じ。
- `freerdp`以外に特に良いツールも見つけられず……。

……なのでビルドしてみました。
私のCentOS環境にはC++をコンパイルできる環境が無かったので
コメントで @take88 さんが上げている[コンパイル手順](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Compilation)をそのまま実行できませんでした。
ですので、まずC++のコンパイル環境を整えてから手順を実行しました。

> 1. ベースとなる依存環境をインストール
>
>    `sudo yum install gcc cmake ninja-build openssl-devel libX11-devel libXext-devel libXinerama-devel libXcursor-devel libXi-devel libXdamage-devel libXv-devel libxkbfile-devel alsa-lib-devel cups-devel ffmpeg-devel glib2-devel`
> 2. ビルド
>
>    `cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DWITH_SSE2=ON .`
> 3. インストール
>
>    `cmake --build . --target install`

`--target package`も出来るようですが、諸事情あってあきらめました。
`which xfreerdp`と`xfreerdp --version`にてインストールされていることを確認できました。
（ただ、なんか思ってたのと違って、複数のモニターを1つのモニターとして認識するような感じでした）

[image: RDPモニター設定SS]

※引き続き調べては見ますが、特に他に良い方法もなければこちらの方法でFIXします。

Comment: VNCでマルチディスプレイ環境に接続した場合にも、ビューワ側では一つのモニタとして表示されるようです。 - 参考: https://qwerty.work/blog/2017/11/ultravnc-multimonitor-dualdisplay.php

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。RDPの接続先の環境を変えることが出来ないのでVNCを使うことはないと思いますが、拡張接続(?)を行うためにはクライアントソフト側に何かしらが必要そうですね。